# Vue.js - Remove verbose bootstrap Input field code with component or similar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, vuejs2

In a single file component with pug template I have many input fields with identical formatting, such as:

```
 .input-group.input-group-sm
     .input-group-addon Purchase Price
      input.form-control(v-model='purchase_price')

  .input-group.input-group-sm
    .input-group-addon Net Rental Income
    input.form-control(v-model='rental_income_net')
```

All input fields have data properties that are modified with v-model within the component.

I would like to produce the same formatting and output, yet somehow extract the bootstrap field boilerplate and just be able to write something simple like:

```
cell(title='Purchase Price' v-model='purchase_price') 
cell(title='Net Rental Income' v-model='rental_income_net')
```

The above doesnt work and input fields don’t seem to accept slots. Also, I don’t want to have to write verbose event listeners, just have tidy code similar to the above.

Is that possible?

Comment: It should work fine if you implement `v-model` properly on the cell component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know pug very well, so this is in vanilla HTML. Here is a cell component example that you could convert into a single file component.

```
Vue.component("cell", {
  props:["value", "title"],
  template: `
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
      <div class="input-group-addon">{{title}}</div>
      <input class="form-control" v-model="internalValue">
    </div>
  `,
  computed:{
    internalValue:{
      get() {return this.value},
      set(v) {this.$emit("input", v)}
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. How is the event emitter picked up in the parent?? All I have is:

    cell(title='Purchase Price' v-model='purchase_price')

Comment: @Branksy `v-model` listens for the `input` event. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bert. Works. Here's also [Simon Herteby's answer](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/remove-verbose-bootstrap-input-field-code-with-component-or-similar/21385) from Vue forum as Single File Component:

```
<template lang='pug'>
  .input-group.input-group-sm
    .input-group-addon {{ title }}
    input.form-control(v-model='interface')
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    props: ['title', 'value'],
    name: 'Cell',
    computed: {
      interface: {
        get(){
          return this.value
        },
        set(val){
          this.$emit('input', val)
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```